# What is the right syntax for MySQL TOP?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query? It's printing the else statement, and it's giving the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2 * FROM `sql_tbl`' at line 1.

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM `sql_tbl`
```

Comment: TOP is SQL Server, MySQL uses LIMIT instead.

Comment: @zlen The 2 has nothing to do with it. `Top x` is not valid in MySQL.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling : SELECT ``TOP`` FROM ``sql_tbl`` is valid

Comment: @zlen no it isn't. This is MySQL

Comment: you may even want to use `MAX()` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent "TOP" syntax in MySQL is "LIMIT":

So:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM `sql_tbl`
```

becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM `sql_tbl` LIMIT 2
```